# Apache Kafka: How to check, that an event has been fully handled?

Tags: events, apache-kafka

I am facing an issue when decoupling two systems by an event/message broker like Apache Kafka. The issue is related to a frontend triggering actions in a backend:

How does the producer (frontend service) know, that the published event has been properly handled by all the backend services (as consumers), if the publisher does not know neither the "identities" nor the count of consuming backends?

To be precise: Users can change for example their email address using a frontend UI. An associated service publishes that "change request" event to an appropriate topic within Kafka. The UI form is then "locked" to prevent subsequent change requests, until the change event has been fully processed by every consumer. But it's unclear how to detect this state.

Answer (score 2):

You can use another topic to publish handled jobs. So your front-end publishes to one topic and your back-end publishes to another once it is done.

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka terms, neither the producer nor consumer are considered backend - they're both clients connecting to a broker, which is generally considered to be the backend.

A producer will know that it has produced a message successfully, by virtue of the `acks` setting. A consumer will read a message, and then at a later point, its offset will be updated to a point corresponding to the last message it read. However, there is generally no interaction between a producer and a consumer, and they are generally completely unaware of one another.

Comment: So, leaving Kafka specifics aside: What ways are available to realize a "pseudo-synchronous" architecture, so the emitter of an event knows that the event has been handled (consumed) by all appropriate listeners?

Option 1: Producer one maintains a list of consumers (which in turn use some kind of discovery to introduce themselves). Each consumer triggers a "done" event after the original event has been handled, the producer subscribes to the appropriate topic.
Option 2: Event is handled by all consumers in order and the final consumer emitts an "all done" event. Looks like an ESB/BPM tool.